# Initialize variables inside a switch statement

Tags: c, switch-statement

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    int a = 1;
    switch(a) {
        int i = 2;
        case 1: printf("%d",i);
                break;
        default: printf("Hello\n");
    }
}
```

The following code sample is giving 36 as the output. How is this possible? I understand that the compiler will transfer the control to case 1 directly, without evaluating `i`. But, why am I getting the output as 36?

PS: I am using GCC.

Comment: Why is this tagged under java?

Comment: How will that help ? @GAURANGVYAS

Comment: I get `0`, so I suspect you're triggering undefined behavior (at least in C).

Comment: This is not C++ either

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ this code is ill-formed because you cannot jump into the scope of a variable.

In C the code is undefined behaviour: `int i;` inside the switch block exists, however by jumping to `case 1:` you bypassed the part where the value `2` would have been assigned to `i`.  So in fact you are attempting to print an uninitialized variable.

Comment: So, the output - 36 I am getting is an Garbage value?

Comment: @KarthikBhat It's [undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/1505939)